# setting number of rows and columns of QGenericMatrix at runtime

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic

is there a way to set the dimensions of a `QGenericMatrix` instance at runtime ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. [`QGenericMatrix` is a template class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgenericmatrix.html#details), and takes its row and columns as a template parameter:

> The `QGenericMatrix` template has three parameters:
>
> `N`   Number of columns.
> `M` Number of rows.
> `T` Element type that is visible to users of the class.

Seeing as one [cannot construct a template without providing all of its parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters):

> In order for a template to be instantiated, every template parameter (type, non-type, or template) must be replaced by a corresponding template argument.

And there's nothing else in [`QGenericMatrix`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgenericmatrix.html) that would allow you to change its size, you cannot change its row or column at run-time.